# Remove an element from one list who matches another element from another list

Tags: c#

I have two list with the next values:

List A:

- '9999'
- '1111'

List B:

- '1111'

I want to remove from List A the element who matches with anyone of the list B. In this case
list A (or a new list) should have:

List C:

- '9999'

I was looking for an optimus way of do it but I can't find anyone. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
List<Integer> result = listA.Except(listB).ToList();
```

Comment: Note, that `Except` has *side effect*: all *duplicates* within `ListA` will be *removed*, e.g. `{"9999", "1111", "2222", "2222"}` will be `{"9999", "2222"}`